# How to identify each UIView uniquely?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I have a class like this:

```
class foo: UIView
{
   static let childView: UIView

   static func addView(onView: UIView)
   {
       //add childView onto onView
   }

   static func removeView(onView: UIView)
   {
       //remove childView from onView
   }
}
```

I want to identify each onView separately, i.e.
If I do like this in a `viewController`

```
foo.addView(onView: self.view)
foo.addView(onView: self.view)
```

It should not remove childView only by calling `removeView(onView: self.view)` once, in-fact it should also call like this in order to remove child view

```
removeView(onView: self.view)
removeView(onView: self.view)
```

For this purpose, I need to identify each UIView separately.

How to identify each `onView` separately, and the number of times the child view add function is called for it ?

p.s I had tried this with accessibilityIdentifier and set a string tag when add view function is called, and increase the tag if onView has an associated tag with it. And in remove view, I am removing the child view, only if the tag value goes 0.
This somehow achieved what I want, but I am doubting on accessibilityIdentifier, will this disturb some built in functionality.

what apple says is: [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilityidentification/1623132-accessibilityidentifier)

[image]

But don't know what UI Automation Interfaces is, and what is accessibility label.

**Edit:** (Code inside functions)

```
static func addView(onView: UIView)
{
    if let iden = onView.accessibilityIdentifier,
       let identifier = Int(iden)
        {
            if identifier == 0
            {
                onView.accessibilityIdentifier = "1"
                showHud(onView: onView)
            }
            else
            {
                onView.accessibilityIdentifier = "\(identifier + 1)"
            }
        }
        else
        {
            onView.accessibilityIdentifier = "1"
            showHud(onView: onView)
        }
}

static func removeView(fromView: UIView)
{
        if let iden = fromView.accessibilityIdentifier,
           let identifier = Int(iden)
        {
            if identifier == 1
            {
                fromView.accessibilityIdentifier = "0"
                childView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            else
            {
                if identifier > 1
                {
                    fromView.accessibilityIdentifier = "\(identifier - 1)"
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            fromView.accessibilityIdentifier = "0"
            childView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with using UIView's subviews and addSubview?

Comment: Why doesn't a simple tag value work? Please show more code. Enough for some of us to actually duplicate what you are facing.

Comment: Why are these methods static???

Comment: @Sh_Khan I am adding the code. Check!

Comment: @cora The problem with adding and removing subviews is that you don't have the count of how many times a same subview is added on a uiview. And the subview which has been added say 3 times, could be removed by only calling viewX.removeFromSuperview() once.

Moreover, extensions could not have stored properties, which may solve the problem.

Comment: @matt these are static so I may don't have to create a instance every time I need to add a subview, I just want to call it like this foo.addsubView(...)

Comment: @dfd Ok so I didn't used the tag property because I've seen people using tag for several purposes, say if i use a tag value for a uiview, and the programmer used the tag value for the same view for another purpose and mutate the value, I would loose the count of times addView() is called, resulting in a potential logical error.

Comment: So it sounds like a design issue to me. And certainly, using an accessibility tag is not going to work. (It also add noise to your *real* issue.) @matt has a good question that your answer doesn't work for me - why static? Maybe if you post more code that exposes what you want would help. Now, a few stupid questions from me - are you trying to add hundreds of the same view? Are you (high level thought) working on a message app and new to uniquely identify each and every message so you can selectively delete specific messages in a specific conversation? I'm not understanding your code need.

Comment: @dfd seems like I am low on description. addView(onView: ) actually adds an activity indicator on a uiview. The real Scenario is: I actually want to show an activity indicator on any UIView. It goes like, suppose I want to make an api call, so at the start of the call I call it upon self.view of uiViewController, and as the response is received, I remove that activity indicator. Now suppose a scenario in which I make 2 api calls asynchronously, at the start of both api calls, I call the addView function, I want now that remove func only removes activity when both responses are received.

Comment: Basically, if you are familiar with MBProgressHud, I am actually trying to replicate it. It works like, progressHud.add(onView: ...), and if you call it twice for the same view, you will have to call the remove/hide function twice as well. And the sole reason for making these methods static is that, I would not need to make instance of it everytime in a viewController where I need to use it. I want to call it directly for a view like foo.addView(onView: self.view), for this purpose it needs to be static.